# in nativescript with angular, when keyboard is open, it pushes my element (action bar) out of the screen (ANDROID)

Tags: android, listview, keyboard, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have an issue on my android keyboard in nativescript with Angular.

I'm trying to make a messaging service like whatsapp and i have an issue when i try to write a message on Android.

[here's my interface (forget the paint S image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncrah.png)

and when i tap on the input area i have this

[when my keyboard is open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBRtE.png)

as you see my listview and my action-bar are pushed like the input area. But, on an other app i made, i don't have this issue (only the input aera is pushed)

[before tapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcle3.png)

[after tapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dix5.png)

here is html code:

```html
<ActionBar title="{{other.name}}"
           class="app-action-bar">
    <NavigationButton text=""
                      android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back"
                      (tap)="goback()"></NavigationButton>
</ActionBar>

<GridLayout rows="*, auto">
    <ListView #chatBox
              separatorColor="transparent"
              [items]="messages"
              (loaded)="scrollChatToBottom()"
              row="0"
              style="height:100%"
              (tap)="hidekeyboard()">

        <ng-template let-item="item">
            <GridLayout class="bubble-container">
                <StackLayout isUserInteractionEnabled="false"
                             [class]="bubbleClass(item)">
                    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                        <Image src="res://ic_trombone"
                               class="icon-attach"
                               *ngIf="item.attachment"></Image>
                        <Label editable="false"
                               class="message-content"
                               textWrap="true"
                               [text]="item.content"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <Label [text]="item.date | timeAgo"
                           class="message-date"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
                <Label editable="false"
                       *ngIf="item.sender.name != 'Moi' && item.sender.name != mename "
                       [style.background-color]="item.sender.pictureUrl"
                       [style.color]="getBestcontrastColor(other.pictureUrl)"
                       class="content-avatar"
                       text="{{makeinitial(other.name)}}"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>

    <StackLayout row="1"
                 *ngIf="status!='résolu'"
                 class="background">
        <GridLayout rows="*,*"
                    class="message-box">

            <GridLayout row="0"
                        columns="*,auto"
                        class="message-box-field">
                <Image *ngIf="newMessage.text.length==0"
                       class="fa attach"
                       src="res://ic_trombone"
                       col="0">
                </Image>
                <TextView #newMessage
                          editable="true"
                          (focus)="onfocused()"
                          hint="Write a message..."
                          textWrap="true"
                          [(ngModel)]="newMessage.text"
                          (ngModelChange)="textChanged($event)"
                          [style.height]="textHeight"
                          [style.width]="textWidth"
                          class="write-message-field"
                          col="1"></TextView>
            </GridLayout>


            <GridLayout row="1"
                        *ngIf="newMessage.text.length>0"
                        columns="*,*"
                        class="action-container">
                <Image class="fa attach"
                       src="res://ic_trombone"
                       col="0">
                </Image>


                <Image col="1"
                       (tap)="sendMessage()"
                       src="res://ic_arrow_up"
                       class="fa arrow">
                </Image>
            </GridLayout>



        </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>





</GridLayout>
```

TextHeigh is always  "auto" for android.
TextWidth change from 85% to 100% when the user is typing.

So, i don't understand why my action-bar and my listview are pushed on this app...
please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for me it was in the file: App_Ressources/Android/values/styles.xml , I change true to false in `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>`

and it works

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your Android Manifest to make sure you have this config?
"android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes I have it in my Android Manifest

Comment: is it the same on both app (the correct one and the wrong one)?

Comment: Yes on both app

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Did you solve the problem?   @julienalbenque

Comment: Sorry for the delay, @SaidulAminNobin yes for me it was in the file: App_Ressources/Android/values/styles.xml , I change true to false in <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item> ans it works